# Adding the portion of a line that comes between the first bracket and the first question mark to the end of the line

Tags: bash, for-loop, awk, sed

I am trying to add a section from the beginning of each line to the end of the line in a file. At present, the file is formatted like this:

```
1.1) This is a sample question? Yes it is a sample question
1.2) Are you quite sure it is a sample question? I am quite sure
...
```

What I am trying to do is to add the question (but not the number) at the beginning of each line to the end of the line, essentially making a file formatted like this:

```
1.1) This is a sample question? Yes it is a sample question This is a sample question
1.2) Are you quite sure it is a sample question? I am quite sure Are you quite sure it is a sample question
...
```

I've already done quite a bit of restructuring of the original text file, including removing all of the question marks aside from the ones at the end of the relevant questions and all of the closing brackets aside from those at the end of each line's number.

My rationale here was to use the closing brackets as a marker indicating where the section to be repeated starts, and the question marks as a marker showing where the section to be repeated ends. However, upon actually trying to implement this, I've come up dry.

I assume I would need to use a `for` loop that goes over each line, activates when it sees a `)` and adds each space separated character thereafter to the end of the line until it sees a `?`, at which point it stops and moves to the next line; however, I'm struggling with implementing this in `bash`.

Comment: Hint: regular expressions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assumptions:

- all lines of interest are of the format: `<text>` + `)` + `<text2copy>` + `?` + `<more_text`
- for lines of interest we want to append to the end of the line: `<space>` + `<text2copy>`
- all other lines are to be left alone

Sample data:

```
$ cat questions.dat
1.1) This is a sample question? Yes it is a sample question
ignore this line and do nothing to it
1.2) Are you quite sure it is a sample question? I am quite sure
```

---

One idea using `awk`:

```
awk '
/).*\?/ { split($0,arr,"[)?]")   # if line contains ")" + <text> + "?" then split
                                 # the line using ")" and "?" as delimiters, placing 
                                 # results into array "arr[]"
          $0 = $0 arr[2]         # append 2nd element of array to end of line
        }
1                                # print current line
' questions.dat
```

The above generates:

```
1.1) This is a sample question? Yes it is a sample question This is a sample question
ignore this line and do nothing to it
1.2) Are you quite sure it is a sample question? I am quite sure Are you quite sure it is a sample question
```

---

Another idea using `sed` and a capture group:

```
$ sed -E 's/^[^)]*[)] ([^?]*)[?].*/& \1/' questions.dat
```

Where:

- `-E` - enable extended regex support
- `^[^)]*[)]`  - match start of line (`^`) + some characters that don't include `)` + `)` + `<space>`
- `([^?*)` - [`1st capture group`] match everything up to but not including a `?`
- `[?].*` - match from `?` to end of the line
- `& \1` - print our regex match (the entire line in this case) + `<space>` + `1st capture group`

The above generates:

```
1.1) This is a sample question? Yes it is a sample question This is a sample question
ignore this line and do nothing to it
1.2) Are you quite sure it is a sample question? I am quite sure Are you quite sure it is a sample question
```

Comment: In an ERE such as awk uses `/).*?/` is undefined behavior as `?` is a regexp repetition metachar and per POSIX it's undefined what a repetition metachar after a repetition metachar (`*` in this case) means. ITYM `/).*\?/`. You don;t need to escape `)` in sed - it's on only a regexp metachar if preceeded with `(`.

Comment: updated the `awk` as you suggested; as for the `sed` comment ... I either have to a) escape the `)` or b) bracket it (`[)]`) otherwise `sed` errors out with `sed: -e expression #1, char 28: Unmatched ) or \)` - `GNU sed 4.4`; went ahead and replaced the escape version with bracketed version

Comment: Huh, guess that's a bug in that version of sed. Per [the POSIX spec for EREs](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_01): `)
    The <right-parenthesis> shall be special when matched with a preceding <left-parenthesis>, both outside a bracket expression.` otherwise it's just a literal character.

Comment: I just confirmed that. `echo 'foo)bar' | awk '{sub(/o)/,"x")}1'` and `sed -E 's/o)/x/'` using BSD sed on MacOS both output `foxbar` as they should but GNU sed 4.4 and 4.8 both fail with `sed: -e expression #1, char 7: Unmatched ) or \)` as you describe.

Answer (score 1):

I would exploit GNU `AWK`'s ability to accept regular expression as Field Seperator following way. Let `quest.txt` content be:

```
1.1) This is a sample question? Yes it is a sample question
1.2) Are you quite sure it is a sample question? I am quite sure
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="[)?]"}{print $0$2}' quest.txt
```

output:

```
1.1) This is a sample question? Yes it is a sample question This is a sample question
1.2) Are you quite sure it is a sample question? I am quite sure Are you quite sure it is a sample question
```

Explanation: I told `AWK` to treat any of following characters: `)` `?` as field seperator, therefore each line was seperated into three fields. Then I get whole line (`$0`) to which I concatenate part which is between `)` and `?` (`$2`). Note that there is space after `)` so we do not need to include another one and `?` was already jettisoned as it was field seperator.

I assumed there is always exactly one `)` followed by space and exactly one `?` in each line. If this does not holds true my solution might need alterations.

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.0.1)*

Comment: There's nothing specific to GNU awk in your answer, that'll work in any awk since all awks treat multi-char FS as regexps.